# Stop/skip video manually on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

I am trying to `end` a video when a user clicks a `skip button` allowing a user to skip the video.

I have been using the following, which is all good, and allows me to trigger an action when the video ends.

HTML

```
<video autoplay>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<button class="skip">Skip video</button>
```

JS

```
$('video').on('ended',function(){....
   //do stuff here
}
```

however, I want to do something like the following, but not sure how to implement this.

```
$('.skip').click(function(){
    $('video').end();
});
```

Comment: can you show in jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: in JS code, the 'ended' is there such an event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`end()`](https://api.jquery.com/end/) method in jQuery using to get back to the previous selector.

Description from jQuery docs :

> End the most recent filtering operation in the current chain and return the set of matched elements to its previous state.

---

To stop the video get dom object and then use [`HTMLMediaElement#pause`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/pause) method. Although finally trigger the `ended` event programmatically using [`trigger()`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method.

```
$('.skip').click(function(){
    $('video').trigger('ended')[0].pause();
});
```

Comment: Note that `pause()` doesn't raise an `ended` event though

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is there any way to raise the `ended` event?

Comment: @phantom yep - `trigger('ended')`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan so does that not mean that this solution is tidier than yours and easier to implement?] I really like your solution by the way, but just that this is only one line

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : Update with trigger :)

Comment: It's down to preference and code structure. This one creates the event and raises it on the element. Mine uses the events raised by the DOM and hooks to those. Both answers have the same outcome

Comment: here `this` refers to the `skip` button tho, correct? I don't want to `end` the `skip` button

Comment: @phantom :  if you don't have access to the callback function then use this one.... otherwise you have two options ....

Answer (score 0):

Moving a video to the end of playback is not a straightforward operation as you need to first get the length of the video, then move to that point.

A much simpler alternative is to extract the logic that's invoked under `ended` and call it when the button is clicked too. Try this:

```
$('video').on('ended', function() {
   videoEnded();
})

$('.skip').click(function() {
    $('video')[0].pause();
    videoEnded();
});

function videoEnded() {
    // do stuff here
}
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/NpgD5/1231/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.skip').click(function(){
    $('video')[0].load();
    $('video')[0].pause();
});
```